# If an event happens on average 0.1 a day, how likely is it to happen at least x times in 3 days?

Tags: probability

Example: Retail sales stats, and how much product you should keep in store.

Comment: Expectation does not determine the distribution

Comment: Let's assume a Poisson distribution. I can just add a small safety margin as it doesn't have to be 100% accurate. I'm just aiming for a formula I can use in excel. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not a math guy, more of an excel guy, but I think the answer is not properly formulated or we need more parameters

I ended with this graphical representation for fun that answers your specific question

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCG6C.png)